# Chromium не видит Adobe Flash Player

Tags: google-chrome, flash-player, adobe, windows, chrome-extension

Доброго времени суток, форумчане!

Столкнулась с такой проблемой - скачала последнюю версию браузера Chromium на Windows 7/8 (и на той, и на другой винде не работает плагин), затем обнаружила, что видео на сайтах не прогружается и музыка в контакте не проигрывается. Появляется сообщение: Adobe Flash Player не установлен, предлагается ссылка, откуда его можно установить. Перехожу по ссылке, сайтик определяет, что на самом деле плеер установлен, но не включен. Пишут, что нужно перейти по адресу: chrome:plugins и активировать плагин, но его там вообще в списке нет!

Инструкции отсюда не помогли:
[Плагин Adobe Flash Player](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/108086?hl=ru).
Плеер качала отсюда: [Adobe Flash Player](http://get.adobe.com/ru/flashplayer/?no_redirect)

Помогите, пожалуйста, уже не знаю, что и делать!
Список имеющихся плагинов:[image]

Comment: @Kristya Относится ли ваш вопрос к программированию?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome и Chromium это разные продукты. Будьте внимательны, Chromium - это проект с исходным кодом, у которого есть множество настроек сборки. Еще в прошлом году Google анонсировал, что они отказываются от NPAPI, как результат, все встроенные плагины они переписали с использованием PPAPI. Чтобы Chromium поддерживал Flash, его следует собирать со специальным флагом, а для этого, насколько я помню, требуется PPAPI библиотека для вашей платформы.

Comment: @Expert, спасибо вам!!! Значит, если я правильно поняла, при скачивании готового бинарника chromium.exe уже нельзя встроить в него поддержку Adobe Flash Player, для этого необходимо скачать исходники и собрать проект вручную с учётом использования PPAPI?

Comment: Представления не имею, какой именно chromium.exe вы скачиваете. Совершенно верно, для поддержки Flash надо собрать Chromium со специальным флагом. Более того, возможно вам понадобиться какие-то специальные опции запуска.

Comment: @Expert, спасибо вам за полный, исчерпывающий ответ!)))

Comment: @neo, вопрос к Вам. Вы пробовали, получилось ли собрать так, чтобы флэш заработал?

Answer (score 3):

Chromium 44.0.2359
Поставил по ссылке 
https://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/flashplayer/latest/help/install_flash_player_ppapi.exe

Запустил Chromium все сразу заработало и в chrome://plugins появился flash.
Так же в каталоге /Windows/System32/Macromed/Flash/ имеется файл "pepflashplayer32_17_0_0_169.dll"

Answer (score 2):

[@Kristya](/users/22497/kristya) Поможет только установка предыдущей версии Chromium. Я поставил версию 41.0.2258.0 вместо 42.0.2293.0 - проблема с Flash Player'ом решилась.

Comment: @tema_bond, да, это правда. На предыдущей версии у меня тоже всё работало))) Решила обновиться)

Answer (score 2):

Хотел ради эксперимента поставить чистый Chromium 43.0.2342.0 на XP, оказалось, что он не видит установленный в системе flash.
Из комментария выше узнал об отказе от NPAPI.
Поискал "plugin" и "flash" в списке команд (`peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches`).
Параметр `--enable-npapi` прекращает появление жёлтой полосы с ошибкой, но не снимает встроенную блокировку NPAPI.
Можно включить временно (Run all plugins this time) или для конкретного сайта нажатием на иконку в строке адреса.
Иконка блокировки плагина в этом случае похоже видна постоянно.
Кстати, YouTube использует HTML5 несмотря на разрешение NPAPI.

Получилось также подключить PPAPI flash при установленном в системе NPAPI.
Вытащил DLL-ку из установщика PPAPI for Chromium с сайта Adobe, положил в папку с программой.
Запустил с параметрами `--ppapi-flash-path="pepflashplayer32_17_0_0_134.dll" --ppapi-flash-version="17.0.0.134"`
Всё работает. Плагин на странице `chrome://plugins` виден.
Кстати, без указания точной версии возвращается номер старой версии плагина. Тогда плагин не принимается.
Хотя на этот случай есть `--allow-outdated-plugins` ))) Плагин работает, но ошибочно просит обновить.

Изначально искал портабельный Chromium (есть кандидаты с `chromium.woolyss.com`), но не уверен, что лаунчеру можно передать параметры.
Будем копать.

П.С. Очень подробную инструкцию нашёл на `http://chromium.woolyss.com/#flash`

Comment: @x32, спасибо вам за проявленный интерес и решение проблемы!))) Супер! Побольше бы таких ответов, как ваш!)))